# How could I locate the log file for Google Photos on Android

Tags: android, logging, duplicates, google-photos

I'm trying to debug why Google Photos on my Samsung S7 uploads duplicates of photos for no apparent reason and I'm trying to determine when these photos were uploaded and if they failed a hash check.

I know on Mac and Windows the Google Photos program (now called Backup and Sync from Google) has a log file which I used I before to troubleshoot another problem I had with the photo upload process.

Any ideas?

Extra background:

I keep it simple on my phone and only backup pictures from one folder. I only use my phone to take photos and sync it to Google Photos and the sync is set to automatic.